# How can i reference Server.UrlEncode in an ASP.NET class?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reference, urlencode

I have created an ASP.NET class.
In that class i would like to use the `Server.UrlEncode`.

Why intellisense is not helping me at all and instead of `Server.UrlEncode` it displays the `HttpServerUtility`?

I have already a reference to `system.web`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access that function through the HttpContext object. I guess your class is in a class library in which you should always check you have a context in case your code is called outside of a web context. Try this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    string sEncondedBit = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode("text & more txt");
}
```

Comment: thanks @Naeem Sarfarz.you have save my time.one vote up for you

Answer (score 6):

Because the `.Server` property of the page is an instance of `HttpServerUtility` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.server.aspx

To use `UrlEncode` method outside the page, use the `HttpUtility` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e55w41w.aspx

Comment: Wow! HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(StringToEncode) Thank you!

Comment: That too. But HttpUtility will also let you use those functions completely out of HttpContext.